# opening Add new contact page in Android phone programatically

Tags: android

I need to open **"Add new contact"** page in phone. I searched for relevant Android code. But i didn't get results. please somebody help me by posting the code for opening add new contact page in Android phone programatically(I just need to open alone).

Comment: I mean redirect me to add new contact page...The page which contains credentials like name, phone number, email-id soon on.

Comment: You may do this using intent. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14278850/2166337

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to create one activity with all the parameters you want like name, phone number etc.

If you want to open this page only then you are done, but if want to open this activity from any other activity then declare this activity in android manifest inside application tag like below:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity"></activity>
```

After this, create Intent in your class from where you want to open this activity like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, MainActivity.class)
startActivity(intent)
```